# complicated pointer expressions

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I have been reading **Thinking in C++ vol1** and there is a section named **Complicated declarations & definitions** which depicts the following expressions, that I am not able to understand:

```
void * (*(*fp1)(int))[10];
float (*(*fp2)(int,int,float))(int);
```

Can anyone explain what the expressions mean, and how do you generally solve these kind of expressions?

Bruce has given the interpretations as follows:

> `fp1` is a pointer to a function that takes an integer argument and returns a pointer to an array of 10 void pointers.
>
> `fp2` is a pointer to a function that takes three arguments `(int, int, and float)` and returns a pointer to a function that takes an integer argument and returns a `float`

Although I have posted the correct answers, I would appreciate if someone would demonstrate the decoding of these expressions step by step.

Comment: http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html

Comment: Start from the innermost parenthesized expression and work your way outside.

Comment: @Bill Lynch I know this code is not appreciated anywhere, but is that the only reason you can think of, to condemn the question? I mean, I could be using them as brain teaser or two friends having a challenge or many possibilities.

Comment: @Bill Lynch  It seems you are too clever. If you would write such an answer instead of the comment I would down vote it with great pleasure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a rule of thumb: start from the name of the variable and scan right until reaching a `)` or the end of the declaration, then scan left until reaching `(` or the beginning of the definition and then repeat.

So for the first example, start with the name, `fp1`.  Looking right, you see a `)`, so now look left. You see a `*`, so you know that `fp1` is a pointer. Then you reach a `(` so go right again. The next character to the right is a `(` which means function. Inside the parentheses is `int` so the function takes an `int` argument. So so far, you have a "pointer to function which takes an `int` argument" Next, you reach another `)`, so go left. You see a `*` so the return type is a pointer. Next you encounter a `(`, so you go to the right and see `[10]`. Of course, this means an array of size 10. So now you have a pointer to a function that takes an `int` parameter and returns a pointer to an array of size 10. Now you are at the farthest right, so scan left and you encounter `void*`. So from here, you have "a pointer to a function that takes an `int` parameter and returns a pointer to an array of size 10 which contains void pointers."

For the second example, follow a similar procedure.

Answer (score 3):

`void * (*(*fp1)(int))[10];` arrange vertically.  I will use `X` `Y` and `Z` for parts of the expression we have already decoded.

```
void * (
  *(
    *fp1
  )
  (int)
)[10]
```

`fp1` when dereferenced (`*fp1`) is a

```
void * (
  *X
  (int)
)[10]
```

Function that takes an int `X(int)` whose return value:

```
void * (
  *Y
)[10]
```

when dereferenced `*Y`

```
void* Z[10]
```

is an array of `[10]` elements each of which is a `void*`.

```
float (*(*fp2)(int,int,float))(int);

float (
  *(*fp2)(int,int,float)
)(int);
```

`fp2` when dereferenced `*fp2`

```
float (
  *X(int,int,float)
)(int);
```

is a function that takes `int, int, float`

```
float (
  *Y
)(int);
```

whose return value that when dereferenced:

```
float Z(int);
```

is a function that takes an `int` and returns a `float`.

Now most of this is back justification for what you already knew.

This is, however, a nearly useless skill.  About the only good use for such a skill is being able to decode medium-complex linker compiler errors (anything past medium-complex you'll want to use a tool anyhow).

If it is in code, you fix the code, probably with help from aforesaid tools.  If it is in an error, use a tool to decode it.  Using the tool will be more reliable, and as this is a rare thing you'll want to do the speed cost is not significant (unless, say, you have an error when the internet is down and you cannot get at such a tool.  In that narrow case, you pull out some static asserts and you learn it on the spot piece by piece).

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you come across a complicated expression like this, you need to follow the **right-left rule**

Start from the identifier and then keep moving right-left-right-left-...

For example,

```
void * (*(*fp1)(int))[10];
           ^^^
```

fp1 is ...

```
void * (*(*fp1)(int))[10];
              ^
```

fp1 is ... *(go left now because we hit a close bracket)*

```
void * (*(*fp1)(int))[10];
          ^
```

fp1 is pointer to ...

```
void * (*(*fp1)(int))[10];
               ^^^^^
```

fp1 is pointer to function taking integer argument and returns ...

```
void * (*(*fp1)(int))[10];
        ^
```

fp1 is pointer to function taking integer argument and returns pointer to ...

```
void * (*(*fp1)(int))[10];
                     ^^^^
```

fp1 is pointer to function taking integer argument and returns pointer to array of 10 ...

```
void * (*(*fp1)(int))[10];
^^^^^^
```

fp1 is pointer to function taking integer argument and returns pointer to array of 10 void pointers.

For the other example, use the same technique.

In the real world however, just use http://cdecl.org/ which would simplify the work for you instead.

For `void * (*(*fp1)(int))[10];`, it gives the result as

> declare fp1 as pointer to function (int) returning pointer to array 10 of pointer to void

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone explain what the expressions mean, and how do you generally solve these kind of expressions?

Generally, you don't. In a sense, these are "write-only" declarations. Anyone who uses this in production code for the first time should be warned; using something like this for the second time should be considered a cause for firing.

You could make sense of them by applying a set of [relatively straightforward rules](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html) to them, but a better alternative is to feed them to [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/), and get an answer right away. To me, this is similar to multiplying five-digit numbers: anyone who graduated from the third grade can do it using a pencil and paper, but using a calculator saves you a lot of time.

However, that does not mean that one should be relying on cdecl for code understanding. Instead, one should avoid writing such code in the first place. Fortunately, C and C++ provide a good way to avoid such declarations: instead of writing the whole thing at once, you write its parts.

First, you declare a type for "an array of ten void pointers", like this:

```
typedef void* (TenVoidPtrs)[10];
```

Then, you declare a type for a "pointer to a function taking an int and returning an array of ten void pointers":

```
typedef TenVoidPtrs*(*RetPtrTenVoid)(int)
```

With `TenVoidPtrs` type in place, this is also very simple. Assuming that you give your types descriptive names, there is no need to check the type of the declaration with cdecl: it should be perfectly clear even to someone who sees your code for the first time:

```
RetPtrTenVoid fPtr = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not really a answer on how parse it, but rather what to write instead.
since c++11 there is a somewhat easier way to create these typedefs

```
using Func_I_F = auto (*)(int) -> float;

using Func_IIF_FIF = auto (*)(int,int,float) -> Func_I_F;

Func_IIF_FIF fp2;
```

fp2 has the same type as what you wrote.